# Harmonize keymappings in vmware fusion on win 7 guest

Tags: windows-7, macos, vmware-fusion

I'm having OS X Mountain Lion as host and I'm running Win 7 as guest with vmware fusion. And I'm using a mac keyboard. Trying to enter special characters become really confusing and a pain if you want to enter passwords since the mac keymapping is quite different.

Is there a way in windows to remap the keys so that special characters are as on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Boot Camp drivers should add Apple versions of keyboard layouts to the Windows control panel. See [VMware KB: Using an alternate keyboard layout for a virtual machine in VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005578).

Another option might be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). See the source for the [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Or if you could switch to the U.S. keyboard layout, the Apple and Windows versions of it have all ASCII special characters in the same positions.